# Retrieve one's own facebook friendlist

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there anyway for retrieving one's own facebook friendlist?
For example, a call to this URL would return my bio data https://graph.facebook.com/my_facebook_id. I'm looking for a similar method though it don't needs to be as easy as that. Using standard facebook API via authentication is absolutely out of question. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

That would never work. The only reason you can see https://graph.facebook.com/my_facebook_id is because of how API privacy is structured around names (which always be public). If Facebook were to change its privacy model even that call would need authentication.

Getting a friend list without permission/authentication is a breach of privacy.